# Translation and scale layout Animation Problem in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, animation

I have the view with layout below.

[image]

What I want is moving View B to the position of View A and at the same time move RelativeLayout C up with the same height of View B. The two actions will be done with the animations. Like the picture shown below.

[image]

I am using ObjectAnimation to implement this feature, but when I am using the

```
    float viewBY = viewB.getTranslationY();
    ObjectAnimator viewBMoveUp
                = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(viewB, "translationY",
                viewBY, viewBY - viewB.getHeight());

    float layoutCCurrentY = layoutC.getY();
    ObjectAnimator layoutCMoveUp
            = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(layoutC, "Y",
            layoutCCurrentY, layoutCCurrentY - viewB.getHeight());
    AnimatorSet animSet = new AnimatorSet();
        animSet.play(viewBMoveUp).with(layoutCMoveUp);
        animSet.setDuration(150);
        animSet.start();
```

I find the LayoutC's bottom is also up with viewB.getHeight(), which is not I expected. Like the picture below:

[image]

So anybody can help about this?

Comment: The short answer is that view translation, which is what you are doing, occurs post-layout, so the screen is laid out like the first image then things are shifted but not remeasured or re-laid out. That is why the shift occurs but the RelativeLayout doesn't get taller.

Answer (score 2):

One simpler way to achieve the expected result is to use `animateLayoutChanges` attribute in the parent layout.

```
<!-- Defines whether changes in layout (caused by adding and removing items) should cause 
a LayoutTransition to run. When this flag is set to true, a default LayoutTransition object 
will be set on the ViewGroup container and default animations will run when these layout 
changes occur.-->
<attr name="animateLayoutChanges" format="boolean" />
```

With this, you don't need to manually animate each movement.
When you set `viewA` visibility to `View.GONE`, the parent layout will fade out `viewA` and translate position of `viewB` and `layoutC`.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="true">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/viewA"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/viewB"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/viewA" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/layoutC"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/viewB"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```